# BSOD while playing a sound resource

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp, audio

I have a VB.NET application that crashes on a client's computer with a BSOD error... KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR.

This error occurs at a point where my program does two things:

- Locks the computer
- Plays a sound in BackgroundLoop mode

For locking the work station, I am just using this:

```
<DllImport("user32")> _
Public Shared Sub LockWorkStation()
End Sub
```

For playing the sound, I am doing this:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("somesound"), AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

Now, this sound loops until the user logs back in.  My software detects the session state switch and stops playing the sound.  Sometimes when I log back in, the sound card plays garbage data for a split second, instead of the rest of the audio buffer.  I get the impression that this has something to do with session switching.

Could my client be having an issue where there is memory corruption occurring at the point of locking the computer?

I apologize for the vagueness of this post... I am not sure where to begin as I cannot reproduce the problem myself.

**Edit:**  If the sound is left to play on its own, even without locking the computer, eventually the computer will lock up and then bluescreen.  Playing the sound while locking at the same causes it to happen sooner.

**Edit #2:**  So I've seen it fail now.  The sound loop starts playing correctly but quickly switches to looping of garbage data.  It's as if it is just reading a random location in memory and looping that.  Very strange behavior!

**Solved!:** It was hardware all along afterall.  Apparently this particular model of laptop has a problem where the speaker is installed right on top of the hard drive.  When playing sounds loudly, it creates all sorts of problems.

Comment: It it on only one computer? or all of the client's ones?

Comment: There is only one there to test on currently that is running XP.  I've tested it on 6 machines myself, and can't reproduce the error.  All of them run the same version of XP, SP3, which is what my client is also running.

Comment: So the crash happens when you try to cancel the sound?  It never occurs while the workstation is locked and the sound is looping?  Does it crash if you do this without first locking the workstation?

Comment: Jim, it crashes as the sound is playing, before I get a chance to cancel it.  We just did some more testing, and it does indeed crash if the machine isn't locked.  However, locking the machine causes it to crash immediately, where letting it run takes 30-40 seconds or so before the computer locks up and then crashes.

Comment: That problem with the speaker placement sounds like this: http://blogs.sun.com/brendan/entry/unusual_disk_latency

Comment: @Simon By the way, that's exactly what the problem was.  :-)

Comment: Oops, that link rotted in the intervening years.  Here's a new one: http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2008/12/31/unusual-disk-latency/ and the associated video of shouting at hard drives to reproduce the behavior: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4

Comment: @Simon This was the laptop:  https://www.engadget.com/2009/03/26/8-9-inch-acer-aspire-one-said-to-have-hard-drive-flaw-distaste/  The sound I was playing happened to be the exact frequency at which the arm resonated at, causing head crash and data corruption.  Since it was a netbook with only 1GB of RAM, swapfile was heavily used, corrupting memory.  I had almost lost an important client over it.  Every time we would test code, it was fine.  The client would crank up the speakers to do demos for people he was selling to, and it'd BSOD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blue screen is almost certainly related to defective hardware or drivers. Softwarewise, there's really not much you can do about this apart from putting together a workaround.

You can [perform a memory dump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649) and try to determine what specifically went wrong, or with some clever debugging see where it bombs out in order to try to avoid it.

Otherwise, you're probably talking about doing some maintenance work on the machine in question.

Comment: That's what I've always said, but sadly, my software is the only thing crashing this machine.  The other problem is... I've tried all of these functions separately in another program, and it doesn't crash.  This lead me to believe bad RAM, but it is like clockwork on this program.  I do thank you for your suggestions!  You have confirmed what I've been thinking.

Comment: Wow. Weird. Now I'm beginning to hesitate. I can't imagine that bad RAM would cause it to die each and every time. To me, it seems like a driver problem, but I'm not familiar with BSOD codes. Nevertheless, [Technet states](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957628.aspx): "This Stop message is usually caused by a bad block (sector) in a paging file, a virus, a disk controller error, or failing RAM."